# Bind java enum value to Spring form tag input

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, enums, bind, formatter

I want to bind my enum value to a Spring form tag input. I have the following code for the overall process:

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE("M"),
    FEMALE("F");

    private String abbreviation;

    Gender (String abbreviation) {
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
    }

    public String getAbbreviation () {
        return abbreviation;
    }

    public static Gender getGenderEnum (String abbreviation) {
        Gender gender = null;

        if (abbreviation.equals("F"))
            gender = Gender.FEMALE;
        else
            gender = Gender.MALE;

        return gender;
    }

}
```

My Gender formatter and converter:

```
public class GenderEnumFormatter implements Formatter<Gender> {

    @Override
    public String print(Gender gender, Locale locale) {
        return gender.getAbbreviation();
    }

    @Override
    public Gender parse(String genderString, Locale locale)
            throws ParseException {
        return Gender.getGenderEnum(genderString);
    }

}  

public class GenderEnumConverter implements Converter<String, Gender> {

    @Override
    public Gender convert(String source) {
        return Gender.getGenderEnum(source);
    }

}
```

I am also registering both my converter and formatter in my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class:

```
registry.addConverter(String.class, Gender.class,
            new GenderEnumConverter());
registry.addFormatter(new DistanceEnumFormatter());
```

Here is the controller method that calls the edit form:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}")
public String showEditForm(Model model, @PathVariable long id) {
    model.addAttribute("race", raceRepository.findOne(id));

    return "raceEditForm";
}
```

Here is the code for my jsp that uses the Spring form tag:

```
<form:form method="put" action="${edit_race_url}" commandName="race">
    <legend>Add a race</legend>
    <form:hidden path="id"/>
    <p>
        <label for="name">Race name: </label>
        <form:input id="name" path="name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="description">Race description: </label>
        <form:input id="description" path="description" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="distance">Race distance: </label>
        <form:select id="distance" path="distance"
            items="${distances}" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="gender">Race gender: </label>
        <form:select id="gender" path="gender"
            items="${genders}" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="raceDate">Race date: </label>
        <form:input id="raceDate" path="raceDate"/>
    </p>
    <p id="buttons">
        <input id="reset" type="reset" tabindex="4"> <input
            id="submit" type="submit" tabindex="5" value="Update race">
    </p>
</form:form>
```

Whenever I save a new Race, the conversion from the form:input to the Gender and Distance enums is ok. But when I want to edit a race object adding the race object to the model attributes, the select element doesn't get updated with the current distance and gender values of the race object, all the other fields are getting filled with the current variable values of the race object.

Do I need to include an InitBinder method somewhere? Thanks...